# Conditional Summation Based on Previous Column Response

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I'm using R to run survey data and I've hit a wall. Most of the coding I've done is in Python and I'm really new to R and kind of learning on the job. I'm trying to find a way to figure out how many rows have the same answers in 2 places. For example how many people who responded to Question 4 (which is its own column) with "Satisfied" also responded to Questions 7 (gain, it's own column) as "Satisfied". I'm using readxl to input the sheet and have been having trouble getting an if,then loop to run the way I want it to, if at all, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You should learn to specify your questions more precisely. It unclear whether you want a result that addresses "duplicated" at two particular places ( Q4 and Q7) or any of Q1:QN. Also unclear if any duplication is desired (i.e Q4==Q7) or both values are "Satisfied". And how do you expect to be offered help on what you might be "doing wrong" when you do not show the code that is failing? Do read [Help] , in particular [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This function tells you how many rows contain at least `k` elements of the same value.

```
nrow_repeat <- function(data,k){
    maxrepeat <- function(row){
        max(table(row))
    }
    sum(apply(data,1,maxrepeat) >= k)
}
```

If you want to check for exactly `k` elements, just change `>=` to `==` in the function definition above. In the example below there are 2 rows, rows 5 and 10, which contain a value which repeats 5 or more times.

```
data
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#1   5  1  4  1  4  5  1  5  1   4
#2   1  3  2  2  5  3  5  2  3   1
#3   4  4  5  5  3  5  2  4  5   1
#4   2  4  1  1  5  2  5  2  3   2
#5   2  2  1  2  2  4  2  2  3   4
#6   4  1  2  3  2  1  5  1  5   2
#7   5  5  5  3  1  4  3  1  3   3
#8   3  2  3  4  5  1  1  1  2   5
#9   2  1  3  4  1  4  2  2  1   3
#10  4  4  2  3  1  4  4  4  5   2
nrow_repeat(data,5)
#[1] 2
```

It works for character values too.